# How to assign string types from a enum in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

So I have an enum which contains a set of strings

```
export enum apiErrors {
    INVALID_SHAPE = "INVALID_SHAPE",
    NOT_FOUND = "NOT_FOUND",
    EXISTS = "EXISTS",
    INVALID_AUTH = "INVALID_AUTH",
    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
}
```

I defined an interface like below

```
export interface IApiResponse {
    status: boolean;
    payload: any;
    errorCode?: string; // I want this to be "INVALID_SHAPE" | "NOT_FOUND" and so on...
}
```

I know I can define just like `"INVALID_SHAPE" | "NOT_FOUND" ...`

But is there a way to de-structure the enum to `errorCode` so that it can accept only one of those strings?

Comment: Question: why not declare it as `errorCode?: apiErrors` ?

Comment: And rename the enum to `ApiErrorCode`?

Comment: otherwise if you want just to define the values as a type you can use: export type ApiErrors = 'INVALID_SHAPRE' | 'EXISTS'; etc

Answer (score 0):

As @JBNizet and @AviadP mentioned, just set `errorCode` to the `apiErrors` enum. Typescript will automatically ensure that anything that implements the `IApiResponse` interface has `errorCode` set to be one of those values.

```
export enum apiErrors {
   INVALID_SHAPE = "INVALID_SHAPE",
   NOT_FOUND = "NOT_FOUND",
   EXISTS = "EXISTS",
   INVALID_AUTH = "INVALID_AUTH",
   INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
}

export interface IApiResponse {
   status: boolean;
   payload: any;
   errorCode?: apiErrors // this is the change
}

// this would now be invalid
const invalidResponse: IApiResponse = {
   status: false,
   payload: {foo: 'bar'},
   errorCode: 'something not in the enum',
};

// this is valid
const validResponse: IApiResponse = {
   status: false,
   payload: {foo: 'bar'},
   errorCode: apiErrors.INVALID_SHAPE,
};

// this is also valid
const anotherValidResponse: IApiResponse = {
   status: true,
   payload: {foo: 'bar'},
   // errorCode isn't included at all
};
```